# How to solve an access vba code issue with bang operator

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, recursion, expression

I am using next code in an access form, which runs fine:

```
 Set db = CurrentDb
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Bestandslocaties", dbOpenDynaset)
 With rs
     .AddNew
     ![Omschrijving] = OmschrijvingBestand
     .Update
 End With
```

I used Rubberduck code inspection to find code quality issues.
The issue it gives about the above code: 'The expression "![Omschrijving]" (line 5) uses a recursive bang operator. This is misleading if the parameterized default member is not on the object itself and can only be reached by calling the parameterless default member first.'
The suggested fix is to replace the bang notation with explicit access:

```
.Fields().Item("[Omschrijving]") = OmschrijvingBestand
```

But then Rubberduck reports about this line: 'The expression ".Fields()" requires a default member access, but the type "ACEDAO.DLL;DAO.Fields" does not have a suitable member.'
The suggested fix is to ignore this issue.

Is this really an issue and if so, how to solve this other than ignoring.

Comment: What about `INSERT INTO....` method.

Comment: `rs.("[Omschrijving]") = OmschrijvingBestand ` should work

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `![Omschrijving]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual rewrite to explicitly access the field is:

```
.Fields("Omschrijving") = OmschrijvingBestand
```

Alternately:

1. Leave it untouched (the code works, if it ain't broke don't fix it). Really, this is the go-to unless you want to learn or want to enforce a specific code style for the project.
2. Go full explicit (don't access .Value implicitly)

   ```
    .Fields("Omschrijving").Value = OmschrijvingBestand
   ```

Note that the brackets are not part of the field name, so shouldn't be included if you use `.` instead of `!`.

Rubberduck suggests a strange rewrite, because it doesn't know that instead of first obtaining the entire collection, and then accessing a member, you can just access the member right away.

Answer (score 0):

Property *Value* must be specified with this syntax:

```
![Omschrijving].Value = OmschrijvingBestand
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this does not change anything.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question again, and now understands, that your code works - I thought it didn't. However, _Rubberduck is off-track here_; your syntax is perfectly valid, and there is nothing wrong in using the bang (!). The only issue, I have met, is, that sometimes property Value must also be specified - perhaps if the [brackets] are omitted.